# Detaching and Re-attaching to Emacs server

Tags: emacs

I am already using [Emacs server](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) for some of the problems described in the documentation, For example, I have `(server-start)` in my `.emacs` init file, and I have set the `EDITOR` env. variable to `emacsclient` so that `git` and other programs don't open a new instance of Emacs when they need me to type text or log message. This is working great so far.

I am now wondering if I can use Emacs server for something else: I often launch Emacs remotely through an `ssh -X` session. Sometimes I need to close the `ssh` session (e.g. I need to reboot my local computer) and re-connect. It would be great if instead of fully closing Emacs for this, I could **detach** from Emacs, and **reattach** later.

Is this possible with Emacs server? I believe from things I have read online that the answer is yes, but:

#### My question:

How can I safely **detach** from an Emacs server and **reattach** later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you directly start Emacs from within the SSH session, you cannot gracefully detach, because the Emacs process becomes part of the process group created by the remote shell, and if the shell exists it will terminate all processes in its process groups.

However, you can start Emacs in Daemon mode first, with `emacs --daemon`.  Emacs will load the configuration, start an edit server (even without an explicit `(server-start)` in your configuration), and detach from the terminal.  This Emacs daemon will stay alive across different SSH session.

Subsequently, only use `emacsclient` to connect to the running daemon.

Comment: Thanks! Using this, how should I exit a client (leaving the daemon running) and have Emacs remember the layout of window splits and the buffers I have opened?

Comment: You cannot.  To restore the complete terminal state, you need a fully fledged terminal multiplexer, e.g. screen or tmux.

Answer (score 4):

`emacs --daemon` or `(server-start)` in `.emacs`.

Next use `emacsclient file`, `emacsclient -n file` or `emacsclient -c` for just an attaching.

To leave attach as usual `C-x C-c`.